# How to debug a simple website string grabber

Tags: java, debugging

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to better debug this? I know that it is returning null at `line = in.readLine()` even when it shouldn't. One tier up I have added a catch for all `throwables` but unfortunately, no errors are being printed. Anyone have any suggestion on what I can try next?

```
public static String pullString(int id) throws IOException {

    String price;
    logError("Checkpoint 1");
    URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    logError("Checkpoint 2");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    logError("Checkpoint 3");
    String line;

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    //^ for some reason this becomes null, but on identical pages it works fine. 


          //Removed unneeded info


                return ---;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                logError("NumberFormatException");

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    logError("left out the back");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Well I am calling this method about 400 times. Around the 10-20 mark, it starts return null even on pages that have worked previously. Once it returns null once, it continues to return null on all attempts to connect to different websites until stopped and restarted.

Comment: How come your code doesn't throw an exception on URL construction? in the example you've given the example.com doesn't have a protocol prefix - this should throw a MalformedURLException. Please provide a working example.

Comment: Better? I really didn't think it was necessary because it was obviously an example.